# Clear the NetBeans 8.2 cache

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I created a project in NetBeans 8.2, and I would like to clear the NetBeans cache.

Comment: The linked question is specifically about Netbeans 7 on Windows. This question is about Netbeans 8.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

C:\Users[YOUR_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2

Clear that =]